# View my Textures in Real Time

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I want to be able to maneuver around my project. I'm trying to apply a texture over the top of some objects that I made. However, I can only view those textures when I am in rendered view, which does not allow the movement around the object that I need, particularly in the "flight mode." How can I have it appear as it will be in the end in real time? I'm using cycles.

Comment: You have to create proper materials for real time display, Cycles materials are not suited for viewport navigation, and have very basic real time representation. Either make materials for Blender Internal/Game Engine instead, or you have to bake Cycles materials and apply them as textures over your object. See [Cycles Baking](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=blender%20cycles%20bake) for more info

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of your 3D view:[image]

Just change it to "textured" or "material".

That should be it if I understood your questions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that for me, I often need to have texture also loaded under 'UV/Image Editor' for that object for it to show in viewport.